# Eliminar los . de input y dejarlo como numero entero

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buen día

Tengo el siguiente condigo que formatea el input y separa el numero cada mil y coloca en . por ejemplo 1 millón = 1.000.000 lo que deseo es pasar esa cadena de texto a un numero entero en este caso 1.000.000 pasaría a 1000000 pero no logro hace ese ultimo cambio, en pocas palabras necesito eliminar los . y solo dejar los números

```
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        echo number_format($_POST['number'],0);
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input id="number" name="number" type="text">
    <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form> 
</body>
<script>
    $("#number").on({
        "focus": function (event) {
            $(event.target).select();
        },
        "keyup": function (event) {
            $(event.target).val(function (index, value ) {
                return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
                            .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{3})$/, '$1.$2')
                            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) para este caso:

Simplemente sería:

```
$oldValue='1.000.000';
$newValue=str_replace(".", "",$oldValue);  #1000000
```

En el hipotético caso de que el número traiga decimales con `,` y quieras cambiarlos por `.`:

```
$oldValue='1.000.000,21';
$newValue= str_replace(array(".", ","), array("", "."), $oldValue);  #1000000.21
```

Comment: Era lo que estaba necesitando, me sirvió a la perfección, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método replaceAll de javascript para eliminar los puntos y luego convertirlo a enter asi:

```
var ejemplo = '1.000.000';

var sinPuntos = ejemplo.replaceAll('.', '');

var entero = parseInt(sinPuntos);
```

no lo he probado pero deberia funcionar